# asp.net-mvc newbie

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm kinda new to the asp.net-mvc framework and I was wondering whether anyone had some good starting places.

Basically my boss is wanting me to learn the framework in the shortest time possible as there is a big project coming up soon that she wants written in mvc.

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Andrew take a look here at the [Nerd Dinner](http://www.asp.net/mvc/learn/) example it's what we all used.

**EDIT**

By the way @andrew, I think writing a production system as your first project in th mvc framework may be a mine field.

I don;t know about the others here but it took me around 4 pet projects before I really got the hang of it and how to architect it in such a way that it made writing and maintaining the code both easy and pleasurable.

Comment: Go for NerdDinner its really detailed, after that i ll go for ASP.NET MVC 1.0 Website Programming: Problem - Design - Solution, for a complete reference on building a CMS with pure MVC. And if you want to go deeper go for S#arp Architecture (MVC + NHibernate).

Comment: yeah that's some good advise.

Comment: thanks griegs.  i know what you mean.  i'm scared of getting it all horribly wrong.

Comment: @griegs, Yep, you need to get used to it, specially with specific MVC things like ModelBinders, ViewData, TempData and ModelState. And learn the ViewModel Pattern that will help you a lot.

Comment: @omar, right on my friend.  it's a damn steep learning curve.

Answer (score 0):

You can't go too wrong by [doing the QuickStarts](http://www.asp.net/mvc/learn/). If you then have more time, read the book [Pro ASP.NET MVC](http://www.apress.com/book/view/1430210079). That's what I did to get started.

Comment: thanks richardOD.  i'll see if i can get the book

Answer (score 0):

Try [www.asp.net/mvc](http://www.asp.net/mvc).

They have lots of great tutorials there.  Also, download the framework and play around with the default sample app that gets created when you use the MVC project templates.

Comment: Oh yeah thanks.  i had a quick look but got a little lost in the asp code with <% etc.  :)  but am getting the hang of it.

Answer (score 0):

[Official tutorial](http://www.asp.net/(S(d35rmemuuono1wvm1gsp2n45))/mvc/) is the a good place to start, especially [Technical Deep Dive](http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc-videos/video-8143.aspx) video.

Comment: I'll grab the video and watch it thanks